# JQuery disable submit button till form is completely filled

Tags: jquery, django

I am trying to implement a jquery function to diable submit button till all values are filled please help as I seem not to find a solution to it..Where am I going wrong?

Here is the html:

```
<form action="{% url 'register' %}" id="registerform" class="sign-up-form" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <h2 class="title">Sign up</h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                            <input type="text" name="secondname" placeholder="Second name"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-field userfield">
                            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                            <input type="text" id="id_username" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-field emailfield">
                            <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                            <input type="email" id="id_email" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <i class="fas fa-lock-open"></i>
                            <input type="number" name="idno" placeholder="ID/Passport Number"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <i class="fas fa-user-ninja"></i>
                            <input type="text" name="nationality" placeholder="Nationality"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-field passfield">
                            <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                            <input type="password" id="password" onkeyup="checkPasswordStrength();" name="password"
                                   placeholder="Password"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-field cpassfield">
                            <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                            <input type="password" id="cpassword" onkeyup="cpassword();"
                                   placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" id="register" class="btn" style="background-color: #5995fd;!important;"
                       value="Sign up" disabled/>
                <p class="copy-text">&copy;2020. All Rights Reserved</p>
                <h3 class="copy-text"> Kenya Airways</h3>
            </form>
```

and the javascript:

```
<script>
    //disable submit button
    (function () {

        $('#registerform > input').keyup(function () {

            var empty = false;
            $('#registerform> input').each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    empty = true;
                }
            });

            if (empty) {
                $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else {
                $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
    })()
</script>
```

Please help me solve the above as the button is still disabled even after all forms are submitted.

Comment: this is neither Djngo nor CF issue. Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with RENDERED HTML, script and relevant CSS

Comment: SIMPLEST solution: Add `required` to the fields that must be filled in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$('#registerform> input') selects only looks at the immediate children(input) of registerform.

**Error**

```js
 $('#registerform> input')
```

**Fix**

```js
 $('#registerform input')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="{% url 'register' %}" id="registerform" class="sign-up-form" method="POST">
    <h2 class="title">Sign up</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-field">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-field">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                <input type="text" name="secondname" placeholder="Second name" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-field userfield">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                <input type="text" id="id_username" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-field emailfield">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                <input type="email" id="id_email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-field">
                <i class="fas fa-lock-open"></i>
                <input type="number" name="idno" placeholder="ID/Passport Number" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-field">
                <i class="fas fa-user-ninja"></i>
                <input type="text" name="nationality" placeholder="Nationality" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-field passfield">
                <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-field cpassfield">
                <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                <input type="password" id="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="register" class="btn" style="background-color: #5995fd;!important;" value="Sign up"
        disabled />
    <p class="copy-text">&copy;2020. All Rights Reserved</p>
    <h3 class="copy-text"> Kenya Airways</h3>
</form>

<script>
    //disable submit button
    (function () {

        $('#registerform input').keyup(function () {

            var empty = false;
            $('#registerform input').each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    empty = true;
                }
            });

            if (empty) {
                $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            } else {
                $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
    })()
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector was wrong (form > input)

You were not accessing the input fields which were not direct children of the form

SIMPLEST solution: Add required to the fields that must be filled in

Otherwise have a go at this unobtrusive version

```js
const checkPasswordStrength = () => { return true}; // replace with yours
const cpassword = () => { return true };

$(function() {
  const $inputs = $('#registerform :input');
  $inputs.on("input", function() {
    let valid = true;
    if (this.id === "password") valid = valid && checkPasswordStrength()
    else if (this.id === "cpassword") valid = valid && cpassword()
    const empty = $inputs.filter(function() {
      return $(this).val().trim() == ''}).get();
    valid = valid && empty.length===0;
    
    $('#register').attr('disabled', !valid);
  }).trigger('input')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="{% url 'register' %}" id="registerform" class="sign-up-form" method="POST">
<h2 class="title">Sign up</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-field">
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-field">
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
      <input type="text" name="secondname" placeholder="Second name" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-field userfield">
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
      <input type="text" id="id_username" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-field emailfield">
      <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
      <input type="email" id="id_email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-field">
      <i class="fas fa-lock-open"></i>
      <input type="number" name="idno" placeholder="ID/Passport Number" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-field">
      <i class="fas fa-user-ninja"></i>
      <input type="text" name="nationality" placeholder="Nationality" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-field passfield">
      <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
      <input type="password" id="password"  name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-field cpassfield">
      <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
      <input type="password" id="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="register" class="btn" style="background-color: #5995fd;!important;" value="Sign up" disabled/>
<p class="copy-text">&copy;2020. All Rights Reserved</p>
<h3 class="copy-text"> Kenya Airways</h3>
</form>
```